# Открыть связанный с div-ом блок при клике на него

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста
Есть табличка, при клике на одну из её ячеек, внизу таблички должен показываться связанный с ней скрытый блок, при клике на другую ячейку предыдущий элемент скрывается и появляется новый.
https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/7yeng69d/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("td").click(function(){
    $(this).find('p').show();

});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно при клике просто закрывать все остальные блоки и всё, к примеру вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('table').find('p').hide();
        $(this).find('p').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: а если делать это элемент p не в ячейке td, а вне её, как тогда можно найти этот элемент?
https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/xsakL3zb/

Comment: Вариантов много, давать data-attr какой нибудь как по мне самый удобный будет, и потом по нему поиск